# How to get seperate line details from this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as

```
Array ( [0] => PARTDESCRIPTION
         PartsNeeded:Transmission
         Year:1973
         Make:Volkswagon
         Model:BeetleBug

         ADDITIONALINFORMATION

         BodyStyle:2DoorCoupe
         Vin#:
         Details:
         EngineLiter:1.8
         EngineSize:4cylinders
         Turbo-Charged:No
         FuelType:Gasoline
         TransmissionType:2WheelDriveAutomatic
        )
```

I need to print parts, make, etc separately. How to get it?

Comment: `$myArray[0]['parts']`

Comment: what is desired Output?

Comment: this is a string in array value and you want to explode it? am i right?